# Boost - mmaping a file into memory for reads&writes

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, multiprocessing, mmap

I'm trying to map a region of a particular size into the memory, looking at the docs example:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file

as you can notice, boost version is 1.70.0

```
    using namespace boost::interprocess;

    const char *FileName  = "c_e_d.bin";
    const std::size_t FileSize = 10000;

    file_mapping::remove(FileName);
    std::filebuf fbuf;
    auto p = fbuf.open(FileName, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out
                        | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::binary);
    //Set the size
    auto r = fbuf.pubseekoff(FileSize-1, std::ios_base::beg);
    auto r2 = fbuf.sputc(0);

    //Create a file mapping
    file_mapping m_file(FileName, read_write);

    //Map the whole file with read-write permissions in this process
    mapped_region region(m_file, read_write);
```

but an exception occurs:
[image]

I don't need the parent-child functionality, just many threads writing directly to a mmaped region of memory.

Can somebody help me solve this out please?
Thank you in advance.

Additional debug info:
p is created seemed to be:
[image]

It is also seemed to be that the two following operations did work:
[image]

[image]

Comment: One very common mistake is assuming that everything Always Work[tm], specifically that opening a file always works, and failing to check for unexpected surprises.

Comment: The file is created, although of size 0, but you are right, I'll check this out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, another suggestions or thoughts ?

Comment: Without a [mre], that anyone can cut/paste into an empty file, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem, it's unlikely that anyone can tell you anything. Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik , That is a whole minimal reproducible example, I didn't use the FileSize param, but now I fixed it so will be no doubts.

Comment: It's not. Please read the very precise definition. Your code wouldn't even compile, it has neither includes nor a main function.

Comment: So, you're saying that I "can cut/paste into an empty file" what you showed in your question, "then compile, run, and reproduce your problem"? That's going to be a pretty neat trick: a compilable and an executable program without a `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your fbuf doesn't sync. Either sync or limit the scope to get implicit sync on destruction.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

int main()
{

    const char*       FileName = "c_e_d.bin";
    const std::size_t FileSize = 10000;

    bip::file_mapping::remove(FileName);

    {
        std::filebuf fbuf;
        /*auto         p =*/fbuf.open(FileName,
                std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out |
                std::ios_base::trunc |
                std::ios_base::binary);

        // Set the size
        fbuf.pubseekoff(FileSize - 1, std::ios_base::beg);
        fbuf.sputc(0);
        fbuf.pubsync();
    }

    // Create a file mapping
    bip::file_mapping m_file(FileName, bip::read_write);

    // Map the whole file with read-write permissions in this process
    bip::mapped_region region(m_file, bip::read_write);
}
```